# Why does isinstance([1, 2, 3], List[str]) evaluate to true?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I was playing around a bit with the new type hinting / typing module with python3.5 trying to find a way to confirm if the hinted type is equal to the actual type of the variable and came across something that rather surprised me.

```
>>> from typing import List
>>> someList = [1, 2, 3]
>>> isinstance(someList, List[str])
True
```

Continuing my search for finding a way to compare a variable to it's hinted type I've also tried this:

```
>>> anotherList = ["foo", "bar"]
>>> type(anotherList) is List[str]
False
```

Would anyone be able to explain why exactly the former evaluates to `True`?

And continuing onwards, is there a sound way to check if a variable's type is equal to a type coming from the typing module?

Comment: Well, for one thing, `type(x) is a` and `isinstance(x, a)` are definitely not the same thing.  An object can be an instance of many types (with an inheritance hierarchy), but `type(x)` only gives you its single most specific type.

Comment: Yup, I'm aware of that after having done some testing with it. Still felt like including it in my question as it's often being given as the go-to when asking anything about type comparisons in Python.

Comment: What does ```type(['foo', 'bar']) == List[str]``` evaluate to?

Comment: As expected, it evaluates to `False` since `type(['foo', 'bar'])` evaluates to just `list`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) does not do real [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) type checking. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) notes this in passing:

> In general, `isinstance()` and `issubclass()` should not be used with types.

The `typing` module, as well as the `collections.abc` and `abc` modules it’s based on, use extensive [`__instancecheck__` and `__subclasscheck__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks) magic to make `isinstance` and `issubclass` behave reasonably. But they’re not doing enough to support your case. Nor is it their goal to support it.

> is there a sound way to check if a variable's type is equal to a type coming from the typing module?

You’re not looking for type *equality*. As you have noted yourself, the type of `[1, 2, 3]` is `list`, which is not *equal* to `List[str]`, nor to `List[int]`. You’re looking for type *checking*, which is much more complicated.

Consider this:

```
def my_function():
    # ... 1000 lines of very complicated code ...

print(isinstance(my_function, Callable[[], int]))
```

What would you expect this program to print? You can’t expect `isinstance` to dig into `my_function` at runtime and infer that it always returns `int`. This is not feasible in Python. You need either a “compile” time type checker that has access to the structure of `my_function`, or explicit type annotations, or—most likely—both.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear and concise answer. I most certainly understand why you can't expect a function to figure out if another function always returns a variable of a certain type, but I'd imagine that it would somehow be possible to _check_ if a single variable corresponds to a type coming from the typing module. Although that might require manually checking if each item in a list is of a certain type which would in situations dealing with large lists or nested types(List[Dict[str, List[int]]) simply take too long to be feasible. Yet again, thanks a bunch for your answer!

Comment: @McMuffinton My point is that `my_function` is “a single variable” just as well as your `someList`. If you don’t expect to infer the type of `my_function` at runtime, there’s no reason to expect that of `someList`, either.

Comment: What _are_ `isinstance` and `issubclass` supposed to do then?

Comment: @remus Their main purpose is to let you introspect Python’s dynamic typing, which is based on a simple idea: every object is an instance of one class, which is a subclass of zero or more base classes. Thus, `someList` is an instance of `list`, which is a subclass of `object`. These relations dictate method resolution, so they are readily available to the runtime. Later, though, PEP 3119 introduced ABCs and a way to override `isinstance` / `issubclass`, which is what’s confusing you know.